# Const-correctness in C

Tags: c, constants, const-correctness, mutability

Apparently it's good practice to use `const` unless something is meant to be mutable, but how far do you go? If I have an array of strings, should my function signature include this?

```
char const * const * const my_strings
```

I'm not going to be modifying it *whatsoever*, so it's a constant pointer to the first element of an array of constant pointers to the first elements of arrays of constant characters. That's a mouthful, and the code is nearly unreadable. All this is a simple data structure like `argv`.

I feel as though const should be default and there should be a mutable keyword.

**Do you generally just one of those `const`s?** What's the point of that then, if you can still easily change it by dereferencing more or less?

Comment: For the second half of your question, see the [comp.lang.c FAQ 11.10](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)

Comment: @JohnBartholomew: Thanks. I didn't realize I could simply cast to make the message go away.

Comment: Yes, `const` should probably be default. I believe Bjarne Stroustup has said the same but he had to maintain backward compatibility with C. There already is a keyword `mutable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would generally use two of the three `const`s:

```
const char *const *my_strings;
```

Sometimes I would use all three, but in my opinion the last one is the least important. It only helps analyze the code that uses the variable `my_strings`, whereas the other two help analyze code that has any pointer to the array pointed to by `my_strings`, or to the strings pointed to by the elements of that array. That's generally more code, in several different places (for example the caller of a function and the function itself), and hence a harder task.

The code that uses the variable itself is limited to the scope of `my_strings`, so if that's an automatic variable (including a function parameter) then it is well-contained and an easier task. The help provided by marking it `const` might still be appreciated, but it's less important.

I would also say that if `char const * const * const my_strings` is "nearly unreadable", then that will change when you have more practice at reading C, and it's better to get that practice than to change the code. There's some value in writing C code that can be easily read by novices, but not as much value as there is in getting some work done ;-)

You could use typedefs to make the variable definition shorter, at the cost of introducing an indirection that will annoy many C programmers:

```
typedef char const *ro_strptr;
ro_strptr const *my_strings;
```

For whatever reasons, C programmers often want to see as much as possible of a type in one place. Only when the type gets genuinely complicated (pointer-to-function types) can you use a typedef solely to abbreviate, without half-expecting that somebody will complain about it.

Comment: By nearly unreadable I didn't mean it's hard to decipher so much as it just seems like a lot of line noise.

Comment: +1 on using typedefs. It's worth noting that const-correctness can't *prevent* anyone from changing your data if they really want to. So perfecting const-correctness to this degree isn't always helpful - it more indicates intended use.

Comment: @Scotty: const-correctness can prevent other const-correct code from changing my data. So if they really want to change it, but are disciplined, then they will restrain themselves and the system works. C programmers who are not disciplined cause a lot of undefined behavior, and modifying const objects is one of many ways that they do so :-) So I agree that it indicates intended use, indeed *permitted* use, but I'd point out that intended/permitted use, i.e. the documented contracts between different components, is all that lies between a working program and a smoking ruin.

Comment: I just realized why the three `const`s are unnecessary: `const char *const *const my_strings` and even `const char *const my_string`, in the case of one string, are equivalent to putting `const` on parameters such as `const int`, which is passed by value anyway. You implied this when you said it only helps analyze the code that uses it, but I find it easier to understand this way, since I have already decided for myself that `const` for non-pointer types is overkill in parameter lists.